# How to remove plural words from a string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, preg-replace, pluralize

I have a string of words which has some words like

```
"Cloud", "Clouds", "Application", "Applications", "Event", "Events"
```

and some words like

```
"Access"
```

which are singular but have `"s"` at the end. I want to remove the plural words but I can't write a code to remove s from the end as it will remove `"s"` from all the words. 
I searched on Internet and couldn't find anything relevant. 
Can anyone help me with best way of doing this?

**EDIT:** How do I use CakePHP in my program? I have never used it before so don't have experience on it. I have that String variable in a function. It says I need to install Cake PHP, Can anyone tell me how to use it in the function?

Thanks

Comment: You have to use a dictionnary.

Comment: Use Cakes inflector class: Inflector::singularize('People'); // will show person

Comment: @YUNOWORK WOrse, you need AI for this. A word like 'lives' can be the plural of a noun, or a conjugated verb. You need to analyze the text to determine which one it is, which goes into AI territory.

Comment: Why in gods name did you put the CakePHP tag in your question if you've never used it!?

Comment: Sorry but I put the CakePHP tag because I had found out that it can be done using CakePHP, I was thinking if someone can help me with using CakePHP.

Answer (score 6):

Use the Inflector class that comes with CakePHP.

```
debug(Inflector::singularize('People')); // will show person
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html#Inflector::singularize

> static Inflector::singularize($plural)
>
> **Input:** *Apples, Oranges, People, Men*
>
> **Output:** *Apple, Orange, Person, Man*

Honestly I don't know how exactly it is working internally but its doing a pretty good job with english words and you can even configure it to deal with special cases.

You can configure exceptions to the rules by defining them using Inflector::rules():

```
Inflector::rules('plural', array('/^(inflect)or$/i' => '\1ables'));
Inflector::rules('plural', array(
    'rules' => array('/^(inflect)ors$/i' => '\1ables'),
    'uninflected' => array('dontinflectme'),
    'irregular' => array('red' => 'redlings')
));
Inflector::rules('transliteration', array('/å/' => 'aa'));
```

Comment: It has a whole series of generic rules and exceptions built into the code as regexps - https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Utility/Inflector.php

Comment: How do I use it in my program? It gives error when I use just that line. Suppose if you have a blank document and you want to singularize the word "Apples", then what code would you use for that?

Comment: Hi burzum,
This is the error:
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in /path/to/myfile.php on line 75

Answer (score 3):

There's no easy way of doing this in English: consider `Clouds` => `Cloud`, `Fortresses` => `Fortress`, `Ladies` => `Lady`, `Sheep` => `Sheep`... and simply stripping an `s` off could lead to problems (e.g. `Lady's`)... you might want to consider using a [Porter Stemmer](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/php.txt) or similar